# Code Coverage Quality Gates for New Lines of Code

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

For Java applications, does anyone have any suggestions on how to build a quality gate that would prevent merging new code that does not have at least 80% code coverage? We're working with a legacy codebase, and while we want to see coverage improve there, we want to stop the bleed and enforce proper test coverage on new code going forward.

I've seen suggestions around using git blame and exclusions/inclusions lists in conjunction with SonarQube or JaCoCo, however this would report on coverage for the entire class, not just the new/changed lines, so we could run into an issue there where merges are blocked due to a lack of legacy coverage.

Comment: "prevent merging new code": my personal opinion is that you should not do this. There are always situations where reaching a coverage goal just does not make sense. To make it obligatory will just waste efforts without any positive effect to quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/exussum12/coverageChecker

This tool supports Jacoco format and will only error out for changed lines.

this is written in PHP (so you will need PHP installed on your CI server)

If you generate your Jacoco report as normal and then use

```
git diff origin/master... > diff.txt

./diffFilter --jacoco diff.txt jacoco.xml 80
```

This will fail on builds where the changed lines have less than 80% coverage (and show a list of missed lines), and pass for anything > 80% (also showing a list of missed lines, if applicable)

This tool will also fail for lack of legacy coverage if you modify old code. (You probably should have at least 1 test for the code you are changing). This may slow some changes down but you will gain coverage in all modified areas which will make things better in the future

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Coverage on New Code which is included in the default Quality Gate with an 80% requirement.

Unfortunately, since you're looking to head-off *merging* low-coverage branches into master, that means you're after robust branch analysis. It's in the plans, but we're not there yet. Further, PR analysis (always a first candidate when you're dealing with branches) won't help either because a) it doesn't look at coverage b) it doesn't check the branch's quality gate status (technically there is no QG status for a PR)

As a (somewhat painful altho likely automate-able) workaround:

1. seed an extra SQ project for the branch with an analysis of master from just before the branch split.

- Use a `sonar.version` value of "master"<sup>*</sup>. This establishes your leak baseline
- Be sure to use the `sonar.branch` analysis property to distinguish it from your analysis of master.

1. configure the branch project's leak period to be `since_previous_version`
2. update your branch project analysis job to point to the branch and reset `sonar.version` to "branch"<sup>*</sup>
3. institute a process to check branch QG status before merge
4. delete the branch SQ project after branch deletion

<sup>*Or whatever value makes you happy</sup>

For the record, "new code" in this context means both lines added and (old) lines modified since the Leak Period started. Leak Period can be defined as the last X days (sub-optimal), since a given date (better but still not perfect), since a specific version, or since `previous_version` which will give you a floating leak period that follows version changes. To make sure that new code going into production meets your quality requirements, this last one is recommended but it means that the version string fed into your analysis needs to be kept up to date.

**Edit 21June21**
Measurement of Coverage on New Code is now available for both branches and PRs in all commercial editions.

Comment: I understand that SonarQube can do this on a single project/branch, but how can we prevent merges to master unless new code is > 80% or some other arbitrary number? I'm not sure that SonarQube can provide us with that capability and we want to take the prevention approach to keeping our quality gates passing rather than allowing someone to merge new code, only to fail our master branch after it's built. What we're looking for is to basically compare the HEAD of master  with the HEAD of the feature branch, then enforce a % coverage on the delta.

Comment: See my 2nd try @dforrest.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the workaround. It makes sense, but unfortunately, that would add a lot of time to our build process so I'm not sure how feasible it is. What sort of support is in the pipeline for the new "robust branch analysis" feature? Is this use case something that is being considered? If so, do you have a timeline for the next LTS version with the enhanced branch analysis support?

Comment: "In the pipeline"? None. Next LTS (Oct. 2017) won't have it. The one after that should. "What sort of support?" Still undefined, but we truly plan it to be "robust".

Comment: I think enforcing that new code has coverage of greater than X% is a flawed concept anyway. It might look like it works while everyone is adding new features which are mostly brand new code, but if you have a developer on the team who is regularly fixing warnings, seeing PRs which hit only one or two lines is common, and we've seen many cases where Sonar behaves less than sensibly in this situation. (e.g. the two one-line fixes you made trip up the duplicate code check. Or the one-line fix you made trips up the condition coverage check even though it doesn't touch any lines of real code.)